# Best practice for accessing distantly related Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, coding-style, standards

Let say we have a long chain of Django models, where each references the one above through a `ForeignKey` field:

```
class One(models.Model):
    # fields

class Two(models.Model):
    one = models.ForeignKey(One)

...

class Ten(models.Model):
    nine = models.ForeignKey(Nine)
```

Good! Now image, if you will, having an instance of the `Ten` model and wanting to grab the related `One` instance. This can result in long lines of attribute chaining like this:

```
ten_instance.nine.eight.seven.six.five.four.three.two.one
```

I'm wondering what the standard approach would be to this niggling issue. Do we leave it as is, being inherently descriptive and readable. Or do we aim to shorten such a line to make things more simple:

```
ten_instance.one
```

### But What's The Best Practice Here? Or is there a more simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Properties

My current approach would be to add a `property` to the `Ten` model, abstracting away that attribute chaining:

```
class Ten(models.Model):
    nine = models.ForeignKey(Nine)

    @property
    def one(self):
        return self.nine.eight.seven.six.five.four.three.two.one
```

I can see a downside to this tactic however, and that's the added mysticism involved. Does the `Ten` instance actually have a relation to the `One` model or not? I wouldn't be able to tell without inspecting the model myself.

Comment: You need to define a property method for every nested relation, it's a lot of code, must be a better approach

Comment: @PepperoniPizza Yup. I didn't want to complicate my answer, but yes that's what I'm doing at the moment. It's a bit annoying.

Comment: I find this approach quite good, since I can't see any case where I would need to chain 5 or more Models.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use django-mptt for sophisticated hierarchal models although it can be a bit ott. If you want a simple hierarchy then add a ForeignKey to self:

```
class Number(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True,
        related_name='child')
```

then the query would be something like this based on a unique field, say slug:

```
Number.objects.get(parent__slug='one')
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this exactly. Would this allow be to use `ten_instance.one`? Because that's the goal.

Comment: I'm just saying that I think the best practice for accessing distantly related Django models is to use a simple hierarchy by creating a ForeignKey to self on an abstract base model.